# How to transform coordinate from WGS84 to a coordinate in a projection with PROJ.4?

Tags: java, wgs84, map-projections, proj4js, proj

I have a GPS-coordinate in WGS84 that I would like to transform to a map-projection coordinate in SWEREF99 TM using [PROJ.4](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) in Java or [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) in JavaScript.

Its hard to find documentation for [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) and how to use it. If you have a good link, please post it as a comment.

The PROJ.4 parameters for [SWEREF99 TM](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3006/) is `+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

I have tried to use a [PROJ.4 Java library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) for transforming `Lat: 55° 00’ N, Long: 12° 45’ E` and tried with this code:

```
String[] proj4_w = new String[] {
 "+proj=utm",
 "+zone=33",
 "+ellps=GRS80",
 "+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
 "+units=m",
 "+no_defs"
};

Projection proj = ProjectionFactory.fromPROJ4Specification(proj4_w);  

Point2D.Double testLatLng = new Point2D.Double(55.0000, 12.7500);
Point2D.Double testProjec = proj.transform(testLatLng, new Point2D.Double());
```

This give me the point `Point2D.Double[5197915.86288144, 1822635.9083898761]` but I should be `N: 6097106.672, E: 356083.438`
**What am I doing wrong? and what method and parameters should I use instead?**

The correct values is taken from [Lantmäteriet](http://www.lantmateriet.se/upload/filer/kartor/geodesi_gps_och_detaljmatning/Referenssystem/kontrollpunkter_sweref99tm.pdf).

I am not sure if `proj.transform(testLatLng, new Point2D.Double());` is the right method to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

55 is latitude or longitude?

EDIT: it seems you should simply swap lat and long parameters.

EDIT2: i.e.

```
 Point2D.Double testLatLng = new Point2D.Double(12.7500, 55.0000);
```